# How to run jupyter lab in a conda environment on a google compute engine (Deep Learning VM)?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-compute-engine, conda, jupyter-lab

- I made a conda environment in my [Deep Learning VM](https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm/). When I ssh to it (clicking SSH button of my instance in the VM instances page) and type `source activate <environment_name>` it gets activated correctly in the shell.
- I successfully connect to jupyter lab from my local machine as explained from [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm/docs/jupyter)

**How can I use jupyter in a specific conda environment on this VM ?**

The [accepted way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39070588/10832217) to run jupyter in a specific conda environment seems to be

> Activate a conda environment in your terminal using `source activate <environment_name>` before you run jupyter notebook.

but the [Deep Learning VM docs](https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm/docs/jupyter) say

> A Jupyter Lab session is started when your Deep Learning VM instance is initialized

so that I cannot source activate before the creation of the jupyter lab session.

Any ideas ?

- run a standard jupyter notebook myself instead of using the jupyter lab provided by the VM ?
- activate the environment in startup scripts of the VM before the creation of the jupyter lab ?

Comment: I have seen some threads([thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53004311/how-to-add-conda-environment-to-jupyter-lab),[thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604271/conda-environments-not-showing-up-in-jupyter-notebook)), where similar concerns have been discussed. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Please try out the below steps:

1. **source activate < env_name >**
2. **conda install ipykernel**
3. **ipython kernel install --name < env_name > --user**

After this, launch your python code from [hub.colfaxresearch.com](https://hub.colfaxresearch.com/) and select **Kernel --> Change Kernel --> < env_name >**

Answer (score 0):

The only way we've found to make it see all your environments(conda and new python environments) **is to run a new jupyter lab instance.**

- When connecting over SSH map the 8888 or any other port instead of 8080 `gcloud compute ssh ... -L 8888:localhost:8888`
- After connecting run `jupyter lab` from console. The default port is 8888.

This is one of the ugliest issues I've seen with GCE so far!