# Running a remote kernel over jupyter notebook

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, jupyter-notebook

Is there any way to configure jupyter notebook to open kernels on a remote machine?

[image]

For example, if I am running jupyter on my server, and that server has access to number of Raspberry Pis (or other computers), is there a way to set it up so that I could open a new kernel on the raspberry pi, e.g. `Python3 [raspberry_pi_1: conda_env_name]`? For example over ssh?

Comment: Pycharm has a remote interpreter option and its own jupyter notebook version. Maybe thats an option you can explore.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev you are right, my question is a duplicate. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming by access you mean ssh or sftp access. Here's a quick hack I tried:

1. Mount as sftp folder(ssh+ftp)
   If your servers are already mounted then skip to the next step. You can mount it through UI (very easy for ubuntu) or use [sshfs+fuse.](http://blog.damontimm.com/how-to-mount-a-sftp-folder-ssh-ftp-on-ubuntu-linux-using-sshfs-fuse/)
2. Open this sftp folder as a local terminal(as opposed to remote terminal
   Again I did this through UI but you can consult the above link to do it through terminal.

Your command line will be something like:

`nihal@thinkpad:/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=<host_ip_alias>/home/nihal$`

From here navigate to the folder where your venv is situated.

`nihal@thinkpad:/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=<host_ip_alias>/home/nihal$ cd /path/to/venv/`

3. [Add the kernel using ipykernel package:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53004311/how-to-add-conda-environment-to-jupyter-lab/)

   `$ . venv/bin/activate 
   (venv)$ pip install ipykernel 
   (venv)$ ipython kernel install --user --name=remote-kernel 
   (venv)$ deactivate`

Now this env will be available under the name `remote-kernel` in jupyterlab/notebook kernel menu. You can use this kernel whenever the remote server is mounted as sftp folder.