# Not able to install feature -Engine Module

Tags: python-3.7

I am trying to install feature-engine module on anaconda 
this is the error i am getting
Package is not available from current channels
repo.anaconda win 64 , noarch etc. 
Can you please help me with the problem?
Thanks,
RD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that feature-engine is not available through anaconda channels for installation with `conda install`. I was able to install it via `pip`. Here is how I did it (in Windows):

1. open a CMD and run `conda activate <<VIRTUALENV>>`. This is the environment you create for your project. If you have not created one, then use `base`, the default one.
2. `cd` to the location of your pip installation within that activated conda Virtual environment (mine was within my user folder in `\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\<<VIRTUALENV>>\Scripts`).
3. in there, run `pip install feature-engine`
4. you should now be able to see it listed under `pip freeze` or `pip list`, but not under `conda list`.
5. Finally, go to your code location and run the code. remember to activate that same <> each time you open a new CMD to run it.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

to install from anaconda:

```
conda install -c conda-forge feature_engine
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jupyter Notebooks, it might be the case that your Jupyter Notebook is not actually running the kernel in your (activated!) Anaconda environment (via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53546634/2682000)), but the generic Python3 kernel that only can import packages from your global Anaconda environment.

You can check for this by importing a package that is installed in your global environment (e.g., pandas), while running a notebook:

```
import pandas
pandas.__file__
```

If you see something likes this (on Windows), you are indeed running the wrong kernel (as you would expect the packages to be loaded from the activated environments):

```
'C:\\Users\\<user>\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\__init__.py'
```

Therefore, in your Anaconda Prompt, you have to create a new kernel within ipykernel (assuming `cenv` is your environment of interest):

```
$ conda activate cenv           # . ./cenv/bin/activate in case of virtualenv
(cenv)$ conda install ipykernel
(cenv)$ ipython kernel install --user --name=<any_name_for_kernel>
(cenv)$ jupyter notebook
```

Now, in the restarted Jupyter Notebook you can change the kernel via the menu: `Kernel > Change kernel > <any_name_for_kernel>`

Importing the same package, like pandas, should show the following file path:

```
'C:\\Users\\<user>\\Anaconda3\\envs\\<cenv>\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\__init__.py'
```

and you should be able to import any package installed in that Anaconda environment.