# AttributeError: 'LGEOS360' object has no attribute 'GEOSBufferWithParams'

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, shapely, cartopy

I am using cartopy to draw maps and it worked well previously.  But recently, when I use this package in JupyterLab, I got the following error:

```
'AttributeError: 'LGEOS360' object has no attribute 'GEOSBufferWithParams'.
```

I have updated my Mac OS system to Big Sur recently. I am not sure if this error is caused by upgrading. If so, what should I do?

I have tried to uninstall and install cartopy and Shapely. But neither worked.

Answer (score 2):

I saw this same error when trying to import geopandas. Simply restarting the python kernal worked for me, for now. I did not have to create a new conda environment. I am on BigSur 11.1 running Python 3.8 in VS Code 1.47.

Cross posting the open issue from Shapely that seems related: https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/1038.

In my case, Shapely is a dependency of geopandas: https://geopandas.org/getting_started/install.html#dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after upgrading to Big Sur on an Intel Mac. Conda reported several inconsistencies that could not be resolved in 3 hours so I just killed the process. Then the following steps worked:

1. Remove Anaconda - [this guide is helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182706/how-to-uninstall-anaconda-completely-from-macos).
2. Install Anaconda 2020.11 - The [release notes](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/individual-edition-2020-11) make no mention of Big Sur, but given 2020.11 was released after the new macOS, I took a leap of faith.
3. Get serious with virtual environments and [create](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/) one for your mapping project. I ended up going with Python 3.6 for the environment. Follow [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53004311/how-to-add-conda-environment-to-jupyter-lab) to use the setup of the environment as your Jupyter Notebook kernel.
4. Apparently there are some Mac-specific issues related to geoplotting packages. I followed the advice from [here](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/738) and installed `geoplot, cartopy` and `shapely` without binaries using `pip install geoplot --no-binary geoplot` (`geoplot` as an example).

I know that scrapping the Anaconda installation seems like a drastic move, but I could not find a workaround with the resources available online. Maybe waiting longer could have worked, but life is short to verify that.

Comment: @Jianjian, you could probably start with step 3, see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by creating a new environment in the current Anaconda.

Comment: Glad that it worked. Please consider marking my answer "accepted."

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error. As malvoisen suggested, I did this:

1. Restart Anaconda
2. Anaconda asks automatically if I want to update -> Updated Anaconda(now conda 4.9.2)

It is now working fine.