# Jupyter Lab Virtual Enviornments

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-lab

I am trying to launch Jupyter Lab from my base environment, and then to be able to choose my other conda envs as kernels.

I followed [the suggested approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53004311/how-to-add-conda-environment-to-jupyter-lab).

Assuming "cenv" is the new environment:

```
$ conda activate cenv
(cenv)$ conda install ipykernel
(cenv)$ ipython kernel install --user --name=<any_name_for_kernel>
(cenv)$ conda deactivate
```

However, when I open JupyterLab and change to the new kernel, opening a terminal (inside JupyterLab) and typing:
`conda info`

it prints that the active environment is the "base", not the "cenv".

Shouldn't it print the "cenv" environment? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at the solutions proposed here: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/5290