# Im having problems downloading packages to jupyter lab and vs code

Tags: selenium, anaconda, jupyter-lab, dotenv

Every time i try to download a package it says it isn't available

```
(GPU_BUY_BOT2) C:\Users\tyriq>pip3 install python-dotenv
Requirement already satisfied: python-dotenv in c:\users\tyriq\anaconda3\envs\gpu_buy_bot2\lib\site-packages (0.19.2)
```

Ive tried installing with conda as well when i go into jupyter lab it says the package doesn't exist.

Comment: Try the answer to this stackoverflow question [conda envs and jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53004311/how-to-add-conda-environment-to-jupyter-lab)

Comment: im already using cona o jupyter lab though