# conda venv as Jupyter kernel | conda lists of same venv are different

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-import, jupyter-lab, miniconda

Goal: use conda venv as Jupyter kernel.

I use the same conda `venv` as my kernel in the notebook. Yet, `conda list` is different.

---

**PyCharm**

```
(venv) me@me:~/PyCharm projects/project$ pip show Cytomine_Python_Client
Name: Cytomine-Python-Client
Version: 2.5.1
Summary: Python client to interact with Cytomine.
Home-page: https://www.cytomine.org
Author: None
Author-email: None
License: LICENSE
Location: /home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: urllib3, future, opencv-python-headless, requests, numpy, Shapely, Pillow, CacheControl, requests-toolbelt, six
Required-by: foo, bar
```

`conda list`

```
(venv) me@me:~/PyCharm projects/project$ conda list
# packages in environment at /home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
...
cytomine-python-client    2.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
```

---

**Notebook**

```
pip show Cytomine_Python_Client
>>> WARNING: Package(s) not found: Cytomine_Python_Client
>>> Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

```
from cytomine.models import ImageInstanceCollection
>>> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cytomine'
```

`conda list`

```
# packages in environment at /home/me/miniconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
...
<not here>
```

Let me know what else I should add to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadn't used the right tool for the job; this error was a symptom.

I wanted to access an existing conda venv, used in PyCharm, in Jupyter Labs.

Solution:

```
(base)$ conda install -c conda-forge nb_conda_kernels
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58198701/16852041)