Python package and conda environnement
I have encountered a behavior relative to package versions in different conda environment that I don’t understand and seems illogical. There is probably something fundamental that I do not understand in the behavior.
Basically :

I have a conda environment 'env' with pandas version 2.0.3
I clone this environment with : "conda create --name env_save --clone env
I activate 'env'
I update pandas to 2.2.2
I switch back to 'env_save' (the one with pandas 2.0.3, I assume)
I launch jupyter lab
In jupyter lab, in one cell, I import pandas and check for pandas.__version__ : result :2.2.2
In the next cell, I check !pip list : result: pandas 2.0.3

Is this a bug or is there a possibility that this 'spillage' is as intended ? (the behavior persists even after reboot)

try !conda info --envs I think you are hitting bash, that is either running base conda env, or none at all.

!conda info --envs display both 'env' and 'env_save' with an asterix next to 'env_save' . My understanding is that it is what I should excpect, no ?

yes, and what is the kernel you're running your notebook on?

Python 3 (ipykernel). I did not setup my envs so that I can select them directly in Jupyter Lab. Maybe there is something there that I don't understand...

yeah, regular setup is you tie conda envs to python kernels in jupyterlab. In your case it's pretty clear which venv is used where, it's just not super clear why, but at the same time you haven't done any configuration for envs to be tied to kernels, so I would just start there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53546634/11610186

You, and the others suggesting commands also involving an exclamation point in relation to running pip & conda in cells in a running Jupyter notebook, should endeavor adopt & suggest to others current best practices in modern Jupyter and only use the magic version %pip and %conda that were added in 2019 (five years ago!) to ensure the actions happen in the environment where the kernel backing the active notebook is running. The exclamation point alone doesn't do this and can therefore lead to issues and receiving misleading information. See more about the modern ...

 %pip and %conda magic commands here, most often using in relation to installs but it works for the other subcommands. The second paragraph here goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues. Also in #8 you suggest using pip there. I know that was just to check something, but I'll point out that you want to ...

  stick with using conda as much as you can for robust and portable environments. Only mix in pip (%pip when you are in a cell in a Jupyter .ipynb file) use if you cannot find a conda recipe.

As to your issue, Georgina is who you should listen to. You cannot just switch to the environment and open Jupyter and expect Jupyter to relate to the environment you activated in conda. Did you install the kernel in that environment and then switch inside Jupyter to that created kernel to be the one you used in Jupyter? You don't mention making kernels at all. Read the top two answers here and use one of them as a guide to your options on how to do this, in addition to to the thread Georgina indicated.

Thx a lot Georgina and Wayne. As expected, this is a point I did not realized. I will reinstall following your inputs. What is the best way to manage the environments? A (base) without any package (just Jupyter Lab) and everything in the other environments and launch Jupyter Lab from the base ?
